# Is it possible for a child-site of a multisite to be a multisite itself?

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite with a sub-directories structure like this:

HQ-domain/site1/

HQ-domain/site2/

HQ-domain/site3/

etc.

and I am trying to find a way to get a sub-directories structure like this:

HQ-domain/site1/branch1

HQ-domain/site1/branch2

HQ-domain/site1/branch3

HQ-domain/site2/branch1

HQ-domain/site2/branch2

HQ-domain/site2/branch3

HQ-domain/site3/branch1

HQ-domain/site3/branch2

HQ-domain/site3/branch3

etc.

Super Admin will be able to access everything, site-Admins will be able to access their own site and all the branches, branch-Admins will be able to access only their own branch's site.

I have already tried the WP Multi Network plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/) but it doesn't do what I wish to, which is to create that 2nd nesting of branches.

Hope I explained my question logically and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, wordpress finds out the proper place in the DB to look for a sites data by looking at the first directory name and there is no way to have a "tree" style lookup.
You might be able to hack around it, and implement a tree style lookup by having a more complex mapping function of your own but you will be probably in uncharted territory.

side note: the multi network feature of wordpress is part of it for more then 5 years. If after all this time no one bothered to add a UI for it in the core then it is a good indication that most developers don't think it is a better solution then installing a new wordpress.